# How to stem tokens using list comprehension?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, list-comprehension, stemming

I extracted a series of texts from an xml file (with BeautifulSoup) storing them in a list of strings(each string is a text). Now I want to modify that  list of strings with list comprehension so that it becomes a list of lists where each list-item contains the lowered stemmed words of the text without punctuation.

The problem is threefold:

a) I can't remove the `" "` element (I tried using `if word != " "` but did not have any effect)

b) when I use the `string library` to remove punctuation things like 26-year-old turn into 26yearold. How can I avoid that while removing punctuation (with string)

c) wasn't turn into wasnt

This is the list that I am storing everything. I want to remove the `" "`
element and find a way to parse better the phrases with `"-"`

```
list_of_texts = [[stem(word.lower().translate (word.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).replace("\n",  " "))  for word in text.split()] for text in list_of_texts]
```

Comment: I strongly recommend ***not*** making huge one-liners like that. They just make the code hard to read for no good reason. Instead, encapsulate your code in functions. Define a function `def stemmed(word): ...` which stems a word and returns the stemmed word. Then write `list_of_texts = [[stemmed(word) for word in text.split()] for text in list_of_texts]`.

Comment: Noted! Thank you! Honestly, I thought that if I write it like that it would be faster.
Any idea about the punctuation?

Comment: Perhaps use `.strip` rather than `.replace` or `.maketrans`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip